# Eclipse is unable to locate System.in in java code

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the code:

```
import java.io.*;
...     
public void test() {
...
            InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
...     
}
```

but eclipse is not allowing the "in" part of the System.in.

When placing the '.' after System, I get offered many alternatives, but not 'in'.

the error message is given in eclipse is: "in cannot be resolved or is not a field".

I've been 'round in circles with it, but cannot see why - anyone have any ideas?

Running Eclipse on Debian Jessie.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a class named `System` in the same package?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, modify it as:

```
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(java.lang.System.in);
```

Comment: Unless the OP has done something crazy like defining his own `System` class, the suggestion won't help.